# Android Studio design preview doesn't show activity title or icons in toolbar when using basic activity template

Tags: android-studio, android-toolbar

I've been searching for a while now for a way to fix this and haven't even found a similar issue. I'm using the basic activity template from Android Studio which uses a toolbar instead of an action bar. When I run the app, everything looks as it should, activities have their title, up arrow and icons. But the design preview only shows an empty toolbar. I haven't messed with anything that came predefined in the template, so styles are the following:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

In the manifest, `style/AppTheme` is automatically applied to the application, and `style/AppTheme.NoActionBar` to each activity that was created using the basic activity template. In the design preview, which is using by default the `AppTheme.NoActionBar` theme, I see an empty toolbar like this:
[image]

If I change the theme to `AppTheme`, the title and up arrow shows, but there is then an empty toolbar below:
[image]

How do I make the toolbar show only once and with title and icons in the design preview?